# Firewall rule for scaled environment

Tags: scaling, setup

In the `Sitecore 9.1 scaled environment` setup (2 CD, 1 CM, 1 xConnect and everything else, 1 Solr) we need to whitelist IPs and open ports for these servers. Can someone please suggest a firewall set up in a given situation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the info provided, I assume you are using the typical architecture of XP as presented in the image below.[image: Typical Architecture of XP]

For the production environment, without no speical security requirments, we usually set up the firewall rules as below. Please check for your reference.

NOTE: By default port 3389 is open for all VMs. If not, please also take it into consideration.

| Server Type | Inbound Rules | Outbound rules |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Content Delivery (CD) | Port 80 and 443 | Access to the Content Management (CM) server and xConnect server on ports 80 and 443 |
| Content Management (CM) | Port 80 and 443 | Access to the xConnect server on port 443 |
| xConnect & Processing | Port 443 | Access to the CM server and Solr server on ports 443 and 8983 |
| Solr | Port 8983 | Access to the xConnect server on port 443 |
| DB | Port 1433 | - |

Hope it helps and please feel free to let me know if any new questions.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same setup in our staging environment but we didn't have to set up any rule. I guess that's because all the servers are on the same subnet.
In your scenario, I would go with:

- ip-of-solr-server : solr-port (eg. 123.456.789.1 : 8983) on the CM
  server
- ip-of-cd1-server : xconnect-port (eg. 123.456.789.1 : 8983) on the CM server
- ip-of-cd2-server : xconnect-port (eg. 123.456.789.1 : 8983) on the CM server
- ip-of-cm-server : 80/443 (eg. 123.456.789.1 : 8983) on the CD1 server
- ip-of-cm-server : 80/443 (eg. 123.456.789.1 : 8983) on the CD2 server